# How to list the guest machines inside a host machine in OpenStack?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, openstack, cloud, virtual-console

I have a background in KVMs but I am new to cloud. In KVM, you can list the guest machines that are inside a host machine by running `virsh list --all` in the host machine.

How do you do that in OpenStack? How can you list the guest VMs that are inside an OpenStack host machine?

In other words, if you are "SSHed" (connected via SSH) to an OpenStack host machine, what command should you run to list the guest VMs in that host machine?

Answer (score 0):

If your openstack hypervisor is KVM, the command is the same.

In my case, OpenStack was deployed with kolla-ansible, which is the reason that I use docker command.

```bash
# Command
docker exec -it nova_libvirt virsh list --uuid --all
```

```bash
# Output
589d31d4-b945-4f7b-96d0-0bd011320611
6a258e1b-f54d-4ec7-9c5a-53a89c6fd973
e6449dce-a8e1-4151-8f44-1ea9ac221ebe
...
```

UUIDs in the output is corresponding to the UUIDs of VMs running on the host.

While if you use python-openstackclient with admin privilege, the command would be this:

```bash
openstack server list --all --long --host {COMPUTE_HOSTNAME}
```